# Memory Leakage in ThirdParty C-Code/C-Library

Tags: c, memory, free

I do have a memory leakage in an absolut frustrating third party static library...I could narrow it down to the following function "read_LUT". I think the leakage is because of the p = (struct csoln*) malloc(ns*sizeof(struct csoln)); 
But C is very very rusty when it comes down to memory handling... can someone help me to free the memory correctly?

---

```
 void readLUT()
 {
     unsigned char charnum[256], line[32], *linep, c;
     FILE *fpwv, *fprt;
     struct csoln *p;
     int d, i, j, k, kk, ns, nn;

     init_param();

     for (i=0; i<=255; i++) {
         if ('0'<=i && i<='9')
             charnum[i] = i - '0';
         else if (i>='A')
             charnum[i] = i - 'A' + 10;
         else // if (i=='$' || i=='\n' || ... )
             charnum[i] = 0;
     }

     fpwv=fopen(POWVFILE, "r");
     if (fpwv == NULL) {
         printf("Error in opening %s\n", POWVFILE);
         exit(1);
     }

 #if ROUTING==1
     fprt=fopen(POSTFILE, "r");
     if (fprt == NULL) {
         printf("Error in opening %s\n", POSTFILE);
         exit(1);
     }
 #endif

     for (d=4; d<=D; d++) {
         fscanf(fpwv, "d=%d\n", &d);
 #if ROUTING==1
         fscanf(fprt, "d=%d\n", &d);
 #endif
         for (k=0; k<numgrp[d]; k++) {
             ns = (int) charnum[fgetc(fpwv)];

             if (ns==0) {  // same as some previous group
                 fscanf(fpwv, "%d\n", &kk);
                 numsoln[d][k] = numsoln[d][kk];
                 LUT[d][k] = LUT[d][kk];
             }
             else {
                 fgetc(fpwv);  // '\n'
                 numsoln[d][k] = ns;
                 p = (struct csoln*) malloc(ns*sizeof(struct csoln));
                 LUT[d][k] = p;
                 for (i=1; i<=ns; i++) {
                     linep = (unsigned char *) fgets((char *) line, 32, fpwv);
                     p->parent = charnum[*(linep++)];
                     j = 0;
                     while ((p->seg[j++] = charnum[*(linep++)]) != 0) ;
                     j = 10;
                     while ((p->seg[j--] = charnum[*(linep++)]) != 0) ;
 #if ROUTING==1
                     nn = 2*d-2;
                     fread(line, 1, d-2, fprt); linep=line;
                     for (j=d; j<nn; j++) {
                         c = charnum[*(linep++)];
                         p->rowcol[j-d] = c;
                     }
                     fread(line, 1, nn/2+1, fprt); linep=line;  // last char \n
                     for (j=0; j<nn; ) {
                         c = *(linep++);
                         p->neighbor[j++] = c/16;
                         p->neighbor[j++] = c%16;
                     }
 #endif
                     p++;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

---

LUT is defined globally as:

```
struct csoln 
{
unsigned char parent;
unsigned char seg[11];  // Add: 0..i, Sub: j..10; seg[i+1]=seg[j-1]=0
unsigned char rowcol[D-2];  // row = rowcol[]/16, col = rowcol[]%16, 
unsigned char neighbor[2*D-2];
};
struct csoln *LUT[D+1][MGROUP];  // storing 4 .. D
```

Comment: Without reading too carefully - You need to `free(LUT[d][k])` for each `d` and `k` that has been `malloc`ed (and not copied) when you are done with it.

Comment: Standard warning: Do no cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! C is **not** C++!

Comment: If that is C, why adding the C++ tag? C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Sorry, changed the flags. mhh where do I have to performe free(LUT[d][k])? I always get a sigabort when I try to free some variable...

Comment: I'm afraid that because "LUT[d][k] = LUT[d][kk];", there may has some duplicated pointer in LUT array. For example LUT[a][b] and LUT[a1][b1] has same value. You may get in trouble if free(LUT[a1][b1]) after free(LUT[a][b]).

Comment: I recognized that LUT is a globally variable for this project. It is set inside the readLUT function but used by other function which are called later...but i cannot find any free(LUT) in functions which are called later...and it is not possible that p = (struct csoln*) malloc(ns*sizeof(struct csoln)); is leaking?